# PHP insert variables into string for post request

Tags: php

My function works when I just have a single string for the $json variable but not when I try and insert the values as variables. Not sure what the issue is. Here is my code:

```
  $myAPIKey = "apikey";
  $command = "campaignstats";
  $id = "9000";
  $date = "2016-01-11";
  $groupby = "domain";

  function call($apiKey, $cmd, $dt, $i, $gpby) {
    $url = "http://data.company.net/auth";

    // $json = '{"command" : "campaignstats",
    //           "date" : "2016-01-11",
    //           "id" : "9000",
    //           "groupby" : "domain"}';

    $json = '{"command" : '.$cmd.',
              "date" : '.$dt.',
              "id" : '.$i.',
              "groupby" : '.$gpby.'}';

    $sAPIKey = auth($apiKey);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'json='.$json.'&sapi_key='.$sAPIKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $raw_output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $output = json_decode($raw_output, true);
  }

call($myAPIKey, $command, $id, $date, $groupby);
```

Comment: **Don't build JSON manually.** Make an array and convert it with `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) , build an array from the data you want.

```
$json = [
        'command'   => $cmd,
        'data'      => $dt,
        'id'        => $i,
        'groupby'   => $gpby
         ];

$data = json_encode($json);
```

Then pass into post fields

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'json='.$data.'&sapi_key='.$sAPIKey);
```

Edit your call function like order $date will be third position and $id will be forth postion.

```
call($myAPIKey, $command, $date, $id, $groupby);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `json_encode`, just build an associative array from the data you have.

```
$data = [
    'command'   => $cmd,
    'data'      => $dt,
    'id'        => $i,
    'groupby'   => $gpby
];

$string = json_encode($data);
```

Then pass it as the value of the post fields

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'json='.$string.'&sapi_key='.$sAPIKey);
```